# Change IE Java Version Programatically

Tags: java, internet-explorer, windows-registry

I need to change the Java version IE uses as we have two independent plugins which require different versions.

Is there a way of registering the version with IE programmatically or by modifying a registry key?

Comment: Huge amounts of work has gone into ensuring that software cannot do what you suggest (automatically and invisibly install/alter plugins) to protect users from malware. I don't think you are going to find a trivial or easy answer to this issue. Much better to port the java code.

Comment: You can change the plugin used from the IE > Tools > Manage Add-ons - see [How to enable and disable Java in Internet Explorer](http://techhelpkb.com/disable-java-in-internet-explorer/). Perhaps you can script this using [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)?

Comment: Alternatively, make the change as per my previous comment and look to see if any registry entries have changed. Use [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) to monitor registry changes.

Comment: Let me know if either of the above options works for you and I will write up a full answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you - I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: @FrankThomas I'm not installing or altering any plugin. I just want IE to use a different version of Java. This is easy to achieve via the console but I need to do this programmatically.

Comment: @heymega How did you get on?

Comment: @DavidPostill There's tons of registry key changes to go through so it might take some time! With FireFox you can achieve this with 1 simple key change. Bloody IE!